# grid view for a widger in angular material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to set up a grid view for a widget I'm building with angular matirial.

Basically I want a side bar with fixed width on the left, and on the right the content with three sections in a column: a header with fixed height (60px), a content which should fill the widget, and a footer with fixed height (60px);

Here is a plunker I have setup.
[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RkvUOsJrs7hjez4MTyk3?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="main">

  <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.10.0/angular-material.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="widget" class="widget-container box-shadow">
            <div layout="row" layout-fill flex>
                <div class="my-main" layot="column" layout-fill flex>
                    <div class="my-header" ></div>
                    <div class="my-content" flex></div>
                    <div class="my-footer" ></div>
                </div>
                <div class="my-sidebar" layot="column" ></div>
            </div>
        </div>


    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>


    <!-- Angular Material Javascript now available via Google CDN; version 0.10 used here -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.10.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

    <script src="script.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    direction: rtl;
}

.widget-container{
    position: absolute;
    top:20%;
    left: 30%;
    width: 40%;
    height: 40%;
}

.box-shadow{
      box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}

.my-main{
    width: 100%;
}
.my-header{
    background-color: brown;
    width:60px;
}

.my-content{

    background-color: blue;
}

.my-footer{
    background-color: chartreuse;
    width:60px;
}

.my-sidebar{
    width: 60px;
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

JS:

```
angular.module("main", ["ngMaterial"]);

angular.module("main")
    .run(function (){

        $("#widget").draggable();
        $("#widget").resizable();       

    });
```

Right now my content view does not appear at all (width of 0). I think I am missing something with angular material, but what?
Also I added draggable and resizable options from jquery-ui but I dont think that is the problem.

Thanks for the help.

Edit 1:
Just a typo, the plunker is fixed and working, hope it would help someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a typo.

In the `div` which has class `my-main` change `layot="column` to `layout="column"`. The same mistake is made in the `div` which has class `my-sidebar`.

```js
angular.module("main", ["ngMaterial"]);

angular.module("main")
    .run(function (){

        $("#widget").draggable();
        $("#widget").resizable();       

    });
```

```css
*{
    direction: rtl;
}

.widget-container{
    position: absolute;
    top:20%;
    left: 30%;
    width: 40%;
    height: 40%;
}

.box-shadow{
      box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}

.my-main{
    width: 100%;
}
.my-header{
    background-color: brown;
    width:60px;
}

.my-content{

    background-color: blue;
}

.my-footer{
    background-color: chartreuse;
    width:60px;
}

.my-sidebar{
    width: 60px;
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="main">

  <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.10.0/angular-material.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="widget" class="widget-container box-shadow">
            <div layout="row" layout-fill flex>
                <div class="my-main" layout="column" layout-fill flex>
                    <div class="my-header" ></div>
                    <div class="my-content" flex></div>
                    <div class="my-footer" ></div>
                </div>
                <div class="my-sidebar" layout="column" ></div>
            </div>
        </div>


    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>


    <!-- Angular Material Javascript now available via Google CDN; version 0.10 used here -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.10.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

    <script src="script.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: embarrassing... Thank you!  Fixed my planker if someone else would try something similar.